# launchd script won't send mail

Tags: launchd

I have a launch daemon that runs but does not send mail. I have enabled it with `launchctl enable system/com.me.helloworld`, and when I load it manually it sends mail, but it does not send mail on boot. I know that it loads on boot both because I see it in `sudo launchctl list | grep com.me` and because I have it print the date to a log.

In `/Library/LaunchDaemons` I have this plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
   <key>Label</key>
   <string>com.me.helloworld</string>
   <key>ProgramArguments</key>
   <array><string>/Users/me/.script.sh</string></array>
   <key>RunAtLoad</key>
   <true/>
   <key>AbandonProcessGroup</key>
   <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Which runs this `.script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

{ echo "hello world" } | /usr/bin/mail -s "iMac IP" me@email.edu

date >> /Users/me/script.log
```

Comment: How do you have `mail` configured? I wonder if it might be configured in a way that is specific to your user account, and perhaps the launch daemon is running as a different user.

Comment: well, I'm able to send mail from root when I run .script.sh with sudo